# a process can't be killed by kill -9, it always change process id

Tags: shell, process

```
[root@rp8 flash]# ps -ef|grep "sleep"
root     17510 17314  0 11:52 pts/3    00:00:00 sleep 120
root     17512 17328  0 11:52 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
[root@rp8 flash]# kill -9 17510
[root@rp8 flash]# ps -ef|grep "sleep"
root     17514 17314  0 11:53 pts/3    00:00:00 sleep 120
root     17516 17328  0 11:53 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
[root@rp8 flash]# kill -9 17514
[root@rp8 flash]# ps -ef|grep "sleep"
root     17518 17314  0 11:53 pts/3    00:00:00 sleep 120
root     17520 17328  0 11:53 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
```

what is wrong with this and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the parent process; you'll probably need to kill that too.

The ps output for each of the sleep processes has the same parent process id: `17314`.  To stop the sleep process from respawning (again, and again), you have to `kill 17314`, but first ensure you know what it is before you stop it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because `17314` keeps spawning it. Cut the evil from the root! (err, do find out what `17314` is before **killing it**)

Comment: how to cut the evil from the root? it is just a sleep process